# Bertini's Theorem small print

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, divisors

Suppose $S\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a smooth del Pezzo surface and $C$ is an irreducible smooth curve (you can make it rational if it simplifies the setting) such that $\mathcal{L}=\vert -K_S-C\vert $ is non-empty. To simplify you may consider $-K_S$ is very ample and let me deal with the degree $1$ and $2$ cases. Moreover suppose that $h^0(S,\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{L}))\geq 2$ (i.e. $\mathcal{L}$ is at least a pencil).

It was my understanding that by Bertini's theorem one could choose a general member $L\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $L$ is smooth (and reduced and connected). I have been told this is wrong and after going to Hartshorne (and Wikipedia and some expository paper by Kleiman that Francesco added to the comments) I am also of the opinion that it may actually be wrong, but that $L$ must be irreducible away of the base locus of $\mathcal{L}$.

However I am unable of providing a proof nor a counter-example. Does someone have an insight on this? I also suspect the base locus of $\mathcal{L}$ may actually be empty.

Edit: Originally $H$ was a hyperplane section. The question is actually motivated by 'the' hyperplane section so I have rephrased it to meet this point. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: You need some conditions on the base locus. What if $S$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb PP^2$ at a point, take curves $H,C$ with classes $11L-E$, and $10L-3E$ respectively? These are both ample (and thus indeed contain smooth members). Here $\mathbb L=H-C=L+2E$ satisfies your condition of $h^0(\mathcal L)\ge 2$, but every element of $|\mathcal L|$ is reducible and is non-reduced. 

Comment: By the way, the Extended Bertini Theorem(s) quoted in my answer can be also found in Kleiman's paper http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/alg-geom/pdf/9704/9704018v1.pdf

Comment: @Francesco that's the article I mentioned.

@JC Ottem: You are right. I have rephrased this to choose the ample divisor I was thinking all the time on. I think in this case it might be true, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Update: For the problem I was trying to apply this on, this is not longer necessary (I solved the problem differently). However, it is something I could have applied on other occasions in many other settings (within del Pezzo surfaces, of course). I hope it gets an answer (by someone not necessarily in MO) at some point.


Answer (score 7):

The point here is the following result, that you can find in Zariski's book "Algebraic Surfaces", page 26. Zariski calls it "Extended Theorem of Bertini".

> **Theorem (Extended Bertini)**
>
> **(1)** The general curve of an irreducible linear system cannot have multiple points outside the base locus of the system.
>
> **(2)** A reducible linear system, without fixed components, is necessarily composed with the curves of a pencil.

Here "reducible" [resp. "irreducible"] means that the general curve of the system is reducible [resp. irreducible].

Now, let us write $\mathcal{L}=Z+\mathcal{M}$, where $Z$ is the fixed part and $\mathcal{M}$ is the moving part. Then by Extended Bertini it follows that the general element $M \in \mathcal{M}$ is necessarily irreducible, **unless $\mathcal{M}$ is composed with a pencil**.

The last situation can occur. For instance let $S=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, whose natural pencils are denoted by $|F_1|$ and $|F_2|$, and take $H=F_1+2F_2$ and $C \in |F_1|$. Then $H$ is very ample but $\mathcal{L}=|H-C|=|2F_2|$, which is without fixed part and composed with the pencil $|F_2|$. In fact, any element of $|2F_2|$ is the union of two curves in the pencil $|F_2|$, in particular it is **not** irreducible.

**Remark.** The situation described in J. C. Ottem's comment is slightly different. In that example, indeed, we have a fixed part $Z=2E$; the moving part, however, is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you, Francesco. This is the kind of thing I was thinking on. 

However your counter-example is not exactly what I was after: $H$ is not a hyperplane section, but rather $F_1+F_2$ is.

So in some way, if $B$ is a hyperplane section, you are taking $H=2B-F_1$. Then it is clear you can extract a second $F_1$. My point was to start with a more 'canonical' choice of $H$. The question said 'hyperplane section', but what I actually really want is $H=-K_S$, which for Fano in dimension 2 is either very ample (deg >2), or has Fano index 1 (deg <1). I'll rephrase the question to fit that. 

Comment: In the meanwhile, though, I think if you take in your setting $H=\frac{1}{2}-K$ or even $H=-K$ what I said seems to be true, namely: any general element of $\vert H-C\vert$ is irreducible.

I quickly went through Kleiman's article yesterday night, which made me think about proving the following: If $\vert H-C \vert $ is base-point free, then the general member is irreducible. This is not too hard using the base-point free theorem (which probably wasn't available to Zariski). It still doesn't avoid (2) of Extended Bertini.

Finally, what does it mean 'composed with the curves of a pencil'?

Comment: Well, in my example $H$ is a hyperplane section if you embed $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ by using the linear system $|F_1+2F_2|$. Often, "hyperplane section" is just used instead of "very ample divisor". But you are right, I will correct the answer. Of course, in this case as you noticed we do not have $H=K_S$. 

Comment: 'The linear system $\mathcal{L}$ is composed with the curves of a pencil' means exactly what one expects: i.e., there exists a rational pencil $|P|$ such that any curve of $\mathcal{L}$ is sum of curves of $|P|$. In particular, any curve of $\mathcal{L}$ is reducible. For instance, the linear system $|2F_1|$ on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is composed with the pencil $|F_1|$. 

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I think it may be true (i.e. there is a smooth irreducible section in $\vert -K-C\vert$ when the linear system is at least a pencil on a del Pezzo) but I'm still struggling to prove it though. I'll let you know if I make progress. I suspect it is probably not true in higher dimensions, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right  in the special case of a Del Pezzo surface $S$. Here's an idea of proof.

a)  we may assume that $K^2_S>1$.

Proof:  since $K_S$ is ample, if $K^2_S=1$ then every curve of $|K_S|$ is irreducible.

b) if $|F|$ is an irreducible  pencil, then $F^2=0$, $FK_S=-2$, i.e. the general $F$ is a smooth projective curve.

Proof:  by Riemann-Roch, we have  $2=h^0(F)=1+ (F^2-FK_S)/2$, namely $F^2-FK_S=2$. Since $F^2\ge 0$ and $-FK_S>0$, there are two possibilities:
$F^2=0, K_SF=-2$ or $F^2=1$ and $FK_S=-1$. The second possibility contradicts the index theorem, since $K^2_S>1$ by a).

======

Now assume for contradiction that $-K_S=C+rF+Z$, where $C$ is smooth irreducible, $r>1$ is an integer, $|F|$ is an irreducible pencil and $Z$ is an effective divisor such that $|K_S-C|=Z+r|F|$. By b) we have $F^2=0$, $K_SF=-2$.

c) $S$ is not ${\mathbb P}^1\times {\mathbb P}^1$ or ${\mathbb P}^2$.

Proof: ${\mathbb P}^2$ has no free pencil $|F|$;  if $S={\mathbb P}^1\times {\mathbb P}^1$ the only possible $|F|$ are the two rulings of the product.

d) $K^2_S\ge 5$

Proof: We have $K^2_S\ge -K_S(C+rF)\ge -K_SC+4\ge 5$, since $-K_S$ is ample.

e) $r\le 3$ and $K^2_S\ge 6$.

Proof: Assume that $S$ is the blow up of ${\mathbb P}^2$ at points $P_1,\dots P_k$, denote by $e_1,\dots e_k$ the corresponding exceptional curves and write $-K_S=3L-(e_1+\dots e_k)$, where $L$ is the class of a line in ${\mathbb P}^2$. Notice that $k\le 4$ by d).
The image of $|F|$ in ${\mathbb P}^2$ is either the  pencil of lines through, say, $P_1$ or the pencil of conics   through, say $P_1, \dots P_4$. Since $-K_S-2F$ is effective, the second case cannot occur. If $k=4$, using a Cremona transformation the two cases can be switched, so  $k=4$ (i.e., $K^2_S=5$) cannot occur either. In addition we have $r\le 3$, since $-K_S-rF$ is effective.

f) End of proof: the proof can be completed by enumeration, since the only possibility is that $S$ is the blow up of ${\mathbb P}^2$ at 1, 2 or 3 points and $|F|$ is the pencil of lines through one of the points.